# How do I prevent a Word add-in from disappearing when I restart Word?

Tags: ms-word, office-js

I often find that sideloaded Word addins disappear when I restart Word, or open new documents. I sideload using this method: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/create-a-network-shared-folder-catalog-for-task-pane-and-content-add-ins

How do I install add-ins so that they persist when Word is restarted?

Comment: By "disappear" do you mean the button that launches the add-in disappears from the ribbon (but you can reinstall it from the Shared Folder tab of the Office Add-ins dialog)? Or do you mean it's not even listed in the Shared Folder tab of the Office Add-ins dialog anymore?

Comment: @RickKirkham I mean that it disappears from the ribbon. When the add-in is installed, the button is visible on the ribbon. After a while it seems to disappear, and the add-in needs to be installed again to get it to reappear.

Comment: Does this happen ALWAYS when you restart Word or only sometimes? Does it happen with add-ins that you have used recently, say, within a the last 2 days, or only add-ins that were unused for a longer time?

Comment: It doesn't ALWAYS happen, but it does happen often (usually?). Yes, it may be that this only happens if the add in is unused for more than a few days. I pretty much work full time on developing one particular add-in, and it has to be reinstalled pretty regularly. I would expect there to be a way to "pin" the add-in to my Word so that it is permanently installed.

Comment: The product team has had other reports of this. And I have experienced it with add-ins that haven't been used for a couple of weeks. It is not something that can be systematically reproduced. It is possible that it is caused by the identity of the logged in user changing. Another possibility is that the local Office cache (where custom ribbon buttons are registered) has been corrupted or just deleted. The best we can suggest is that when it happens, click the smiley face in the upper left of the Office app and send feedback describing what happened.

Answer (score 0):

For what i know, the only posibility is to use the "Automatically open a task pane with a document"

See this link for more [info](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/design/automatically-open-a-task-pane-with-a-document)